# margin-left changes on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

To scroll from left to right I have this little javascript, that works really well.

```
window.onscroll=function() {
var scroll = window.scrollY;
$('#page').css('left', '-' + scroll + 'px');
}
```

But everytime I scroll once to right, and I scroll back to left, the margin of the content changes.
[image]

You can see that the scrollbar is at the top at both pictures.
The first one is before the scroll, and the second one is after I scrolled.

[demo without pictures](http://jsbin.com/umAdeGI/1)

Comment: That's probably to less information you give us. A jsfiddle to reproduce the problem would help...

Comment: Looks to me like its working perfectly and some elements are position fixed

Comment: A jsfiddle will be provided in a minute or two @DominicBartl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `position:fixed` doesn’t automatically position the element to the far left. You should add an initial `left` value for `#page` for consistent results, f.ex:

```
#page{ left:0 }
```

Although it looks like you want to have some more space to the left, so try something like:

```
var init = 200, // the initial left margin
    $page = $('#page').css('left', init);
window.onscroll = function() {
    $page.css('left', init-window.scrollY);
};
```

Comment: the page left:0 did the trick!!! I added a extra margin to the content div, and i worked out perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This happens when css style left=0px. Just remove style left if scroll = 0
See example http://jsbin.com/umAdeGI/2